# Floating magnet wheel

Tags: magnetic-fields

If someone was to, put 2 magnets, spaced out. then put one in the middle, while both are attracting. would it float? I'm just starting to do stuff related to this. then if it was spun, would it spin for a bit?

Comment: Could you be more specific about the arrangement of the magnets?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In terms of a thought experiment, yes it's possible. If you consider a free-body diagram, and you put the magnets in a pure vacuum free of perturbing air currents, and remove other vibrations, then the force of gravity could exactly cancel out the magnetic attraction force, and if F_net=0, there is no movement.

However, in terms of practical applications, if the forces are not exactly equal, or if there's any small perturbation from air currents or ground vibrations or someone sneezing, then the middle magnet would either fall or get pulled up to the top magnet.

Comment: Yes. i was thinking of something like this.

Answer (score 0):

No, that floating arrangement is not stable, even if all the magnets are identical. It's not practically possible to make the distances exactly equal, so the middle magnet will be slightly closer to one of the outer magnets and move towards it.

So it won't work even with a horizontal arrangement. A vertical arrangement, with the middle magnet floating is even trickier, what to speak of throwing rotation into the mix.